# Providing an iterator for the first element of a container of pairs

Tags: c++, generics, templates, stl

I have a container filled with pairs. I want to iterate in it using the STL generic algorithms (in my case it would be inner_product, but consider it as a generic problem).
The algorithm I am using expects iterators first and last. Can I provide special iterators first and last that will iterate not on the pairs but on the first element of each pair?

I know i can do it manually, providing a hand-made function object that will be a wrapper around the standard container iterator, deferencing it to the first member of the pair intend of the pair itself,but I think there is also a clever one-liner to do it for me. What would it be?

Comment: you mean for example you have a map.begin() , and you want to iterate over its values (.second) ?

Comment: Yes, that is another instance of the same basic problem.

Comment: Yes. Boost is allowed. Heck, it is even preferred :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've looked around and found `boost::transform_iterator`. I've come up with this code. Surprising how well it works:

```
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

int main() {
    typedef std::map<std::string, int>::value_type value_type;
    std::map<std::string, int> a;
    a["one"] = 1;
    a["two"] = 2;

    // returns the second element 
    boost::function<int(value_type&)> f = boost::bind(&value_type::second, _1);
    std::copy(boost::make_transform_iterator(a.begin(), f), 
              boost::make_transform_iterator(a.end(), f),
              std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));

}
```

It's printing `"1 2 "` to the standard output.

Comment: It is as close to a "clever one liner solution" as I think we will get... :-)

Comment: you *could* put everything into one line. but you would have to repeat the bind call. ugly code copy'n'paste then :)

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass e.g. std::vector::const_iterator yourself, reimplementing operator* and operator-> to return the first of the pair.  You'd also need to create your own begin() and end() functions to return your custom iterator.

You can also create to binary function classes and pass those to inner_product.

Comment: Are you sure i can subclass stl iterators? I always though that they provided no virtual destrucor, not enabling subclassing.

Comment: I didn't say subclass std::iterator.  I said subclass std::vector::const_iterator.  I tried it just now, and it works.

Comment: you *can* (sorry my comment said "cannot", i indeed meant "can") subclass from std::iterator indeed. it provides the common typedefs needed. its purpose is not to provide a polymorphic interface

Answer (score 1):

There is no clever one-liner solution. Your best hope is to write a wrapper iterator. This is actually a pretty canonical solution. You might check whether Boost already has what you need. If not, try to write a generic wrapper that can be reused for other problems.

The STL contains such an iterator wrapper called `reverse_iterator`. The name implies its use.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, I think your idea is the way to go. You can use Boost to help you do it. To start, you'd need a function that takes your pair and returns the first element. I think you could write such a function in-line using the [Lambda library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/lambda.html), but for readability's sake, I think I'd just write a simple function that does that instead. Then pass that function with your original iterators to construct a [`transform_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html) for your sequence's begin and end.