# Is there an STL or boost adaptor which lets me use vector<pair<string,int>> as vector<string>?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, stdvector, adaptor

I'm used to have a `vector` of `wstring`. I need to store the line number for each string, so I refactored the vector to be `vector<pair<wstring, size_t>>`. If possible, I'd still like to use this vector like a `vector<wstring>` in some contexts. This is my code:

```
typedef std::pair<std::wstring, size_t> LineNoPair;
typedef std::vector<LineNoPair>         LineNos;
LineNos lines;
// Split lines, but don't split at line continuations
boost::split_regex(lines,  // <-- I'd like to use `lines` as the split target
                   contents, 
                   boost::wregex(L"(((?<![_])\\r\\n)|((?<![_\\r])\\n))"));

for (LineNoPair& line : lines)
{
    // remove line continuations from string
    boost::replace_all_regex(line.first, 
                             boost::wregex(L"(_?[ ]*\\r?\\n)"), 
                             std::wstring());
}
```

I could simply use a vector of strings and a separate vector of line numbers, but I'd like to be able to iterate over these items together.

So, the general question is: Is there a thing which lets me use a `vector` of tuples like a vector of one of the tuple's types?

This question is different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312749/providing-an-iterator-for-the-first-element-of-a-container-of-pairs) as I need a vector-compatible interface (including `swap`) whereas the other question is only about iterator adaptors.

Comment: I added a paragraph explaining why the other question is not the same and the answers in the other question are not applicable here, as far as I see.